# how to load remote m3u8 to jw player 6 via php script?

Tags: php, jwplayer, m3u8, jwplayer6

hi all i am trying to load remote m3u8 using php script in jw player but i get the following error:
**playlist could not be loaded: no playable sources found**
could anyone tell me how to fix the above error?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.js"></script>

    <div id='player_1234'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     jwplayer('player_1234').setup({
        file: "./get.php?url=2234",
        provider: 'video',
        width: "480",
        height: "270",
        controlbar: "bottom",
        primary: "flash",
        image: "./thumbs/test.jpg",
        autostart: "true",
      });
    </script>
```

get.php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if (isset($_GET['url']) && preg_match('`^http://`', $_GET['url'])) {
   echo file_get_contents('http://www.examplesite.com/'.$_GET['url'].'.m3u8');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JW6, the provider option is no longer used.

So, change this:

```
provider: 'video',
```

To this:

```
type: 'hls',
```

And you should be all set!

Comment: ethan thanks for reply. I tried what you suggested but the player keeps show that spinning animation for loading. It seems the php script is not getting called properly or the php script is echoing the data incorrectly! could you tell me what format should php script should output data so jw player could read it ?

Comment: There's also no "controlbar: 'bottom'" option in JW6. It's "controls: true" or "controls: false".

Comment: Hm, can you provide a link to where you are running this then please? I need to see that in order to debug properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the .php, jwplayer and most others accept a limited amount of file extensions.

You need to either:

1.- Set up a rewrite rule on your server so that foo.m3u8 gets sent to foo.php and then echo the m3u8 contents through that. or;

2.- Set up a specific subdomain where m3u8 files are parsed by the PHP Interpreter and call them directly.

Also don't forget to set

```
header("Content-type: application/x-mpegURL");
```

In both cases.